# How can I create Enter event when I want to click on button, without using class Robot?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

How can I create Enter event when I want to click on button, without using class Robot? I have already created a form and I create button btnMainOk.

I've tried to use keyListener but it's not working.

```
  btnMainOk.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            btnMainOk.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                    super.keyReleased(e);
                    if (e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
                        System.out.println("Hello");
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

The goal is when I click with my mouse device on button, that button should act like I pressed enter key on my keyboard.

Comment: But if you click the button on your mouse, the focus will be on the button, and an Enter key would reclick the button...causing an infinite loop. If you wanted to do it the other way around it would be easy, just call `button.doClick()`. What are you trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: I have buttons which act like numbers from 0 to 9. That numbers are putting to textField and in the end I have to create enter key on the new button for that textfield

Comment: So you just need that the textfield acts as if enter had been pressed? You could do something like `myTextField.getAction().actionPerformed(myEvent)` where `myEvent` is an `ActionEvent` created by you.

Comment: If I don't have enter on the button I won't accomplish next operations.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Some kind of calculator? You're probably going about this in the wrong way. If you press enter in a textfield, its actionlistener will be executed. There's no way to "add the enter key" to a textfield.

Comment: I agree with that. I have to create actionlistener on the button which will have enter event, and it will be focus on that textfield

Comment: Then you'll have to call the ActionListener directly like I explained.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199284/discussion-between-robhellford-and-kayaman).